# How to store mysql settings?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm developing a web application (a gallery manager) which will be installed on a "web hosting" by people who wants to use it, just like the Wordpress platform.

About the installation, I'm asking for mysql settings in a form like database hostname, database user, database password and database name, but these informations will be used later (to insert the connection login and the connection password in the db, for example). I would like to know what is the better way to store these settings. Should I store them into a settings file .txt ? .dat ? I prefer to avoid because of some possibilities to hack.

The first step of installation is about creating tables after filling a form, and the second step for insert data in the database after filling an another form. I tried to store the settings into variables, but like I am using some php functions, I can't use it later in an other functions (because of local variables, they're not global).

Comment: in a *.php file outside the web root.

Comment: And if the user do not have access to any other location that the web root ? Just like a lot web hosting services only gives the www directory... (Wordpress is doing like that ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a common .php file which you should include in your every other file where you want connection with your database. In that file, just assign values like hostname, db, dbh to some meaningful variables you will be using later, these variables will be available to all your functions where you include this file.